# How do you preform multi spectral image classification on non Landsat images in QGIS

Tags: qgis, land-classification

My aim is to classify vegetation types, using areal/ satellite imagery, in a small (4km^2) area of the North York Moors (UK). This area contains two small rivers and their catchment areas; one of the rivers is in an area of planted forestry and the other open heather moorland. I plan is to classify the image to better discriminate between the vegetation types to teach students about the effect vegetation has on rivers.

I have an area in mind and have done this kind of classification exercise before, however only when following tutorials and using Landsat data in ArcGIS. I now need help locating multi spectral imagery of high enough quality for my 4km area (so not Landsat) and help to classify it using QGIS.

My question is therefore two fold:

a) where can I purchase/ acquire such high quality data?

b) how do I preform classification on a multi spectral image which is not Landsat in QGIS (or is it even possible)?

Comment: For the North York Moors you might be interested the the Environment Agency which has released LIDAR as opendata https://environmentagency.blog.gov.uk/2015/09/18/laser-surveys-light-up-open-data/ (it will back online on 3rd December 2015 due to changes in datacentre locations)

Comment: Thank you I have come across this before, it an amazing resource but unfortunately missing in the area I am interested in!

Answer (score 1):

A) acquiring data - you can purchase high quality data from AirBUS D&S, DigitalGlobe or Blackbridge. You may be able to get free imagery from DigitalGlobe, if your project is applicable for an 'Imagery Grant' - see [this link](http://www.digitalglobefoundation.org/application-process). None the less, buying a small amount of data is not all that expensive, and it will allow you to create good maps and illustrations.

B) Performing classification on other types of imagery is much the same as it is for Landsat. The tutorial may have a few things specific for Landsat, but in general, the approach is the same.
Without a link to the specific tutorials that you have read, it will be difficult to point at specific differences, but it is definitely possible to do classification on data from other satellites.